# Macbook Pro 17" mid 2010 + NEC upd720202 Express Card USB 3.0

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk, driver

I have a MacBookPro6,1 running well and stable on MacOS 10.9.5,
I use it for video image editing, so I have a lot of data on external drives.
Recently found out that I can speed up all transferings via ExpressCard, 
so I purchased one with NEC upd720202 chipset (the only one available here) but it doesn't work correctly.
 There is a mini disk with Windows driver, but I can't find any driver for MAcOS, niether at NEC, nor at Renesas web site. 
When inserted there is an appropriate icon [image] at the top of the screen, but it doesn't see any device connected to USB ports.
I've read many posts about switching SIP, but it is not useful for my OS.
Looking for solution, thankful for any help!

Comment: There likely won’t be any solution because ExpressCard is a dead technology.  It’s being detected by your Mac, but there’s no driver for it.  Disabling SIP won’t enable a device that doesn’t have a driver

Comment: it is important when identifying hardware you want to use to determine if it *specifically* supports Macintosh and what model of Mac and what versions of macOS. Like @Allan said you will need drivers for most hardware, and if the manufacturer does not offer it it is unlikely it will ever work.

Comment: is there any known express card to run on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

**As pointed out, the info is inaccurate for the MacBook Pro 2010 as it doesn't have Thunderbolt yet. The 2011 models have Thunderbolt and the info is accurate below. The 2012 models have USB 3.0 and Thunderbolt, so the adapter is irrelevant**

I'm not a big fan of adapters used to try and improve speed as they tend to not work as well as you expect.

I hunted around for a product that might help and the best option I could find was to get you Thunderbolt to USB 3.0 via the **Kanex Thunderbolt to eSATA plus USB 3.0 Adapter**.

Kanex makes a bunch of stuff for Macs and their stuff is hit or miss. At least they offer support for their products so if it doesn't work you can return it or talk with someone who makes the product.

If you have Amazon, you can find the adapter there, or you can get it straight from Kanex directly. It's a bit pricy though at around $75-$100 USD so it might make more sense to get yourself a thunderbolt drive or put the money towards a newer system at this point.

Here's the Kanex link for the product: [Thunderbolt to eSata + USB 3.0 Adapter](https://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-esata)

*Note: Sonnet used to make a [ExpressCard to USB adapter](https://www.sonnettech.com/es/product/macbookaccessories/index.html) that would have worked, but they no longer sell the product or support it. I would advise skipping the ExpressCard slot on your Mac altogether for this issue.*

Comment: My Mac has a display port, which is not a Thunderbolt yet ‍♂️

Comment: Oh no! Ok so there's no options that I would do in your case. All the products that used to do it are off the market now and the drivers will be a challenge to get if you do find one.